# git push heroku master をすると403エラーが発生する

Tags: heroku

**エラー内容**

railsアプリをherokuにpushしようとするとエラーがでます。

```
$ git push heroku master
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://git.heroku.com/mymemo.git/info/refs
```

.git/configの内容は下記のとおりです。

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true 
[remote "heroku"]
        url = https://git.heroku.com/mymemo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

herokuにはログイン済みの状態です。

ネットで複数の情報を参照しましたが、GitHubのアカウントを～～という情報があるのですが、herokuを使うにはGitHubのアカウントがないとだめなのでしょうか？

複数情報ソースをみたかんじだとGitHubの登録は必須ではなさそうなのですが、どうしたら解決するのでしょうか？ネットで検索しても有用な回答が見つかりません。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

まずは `heroku create` を実行します。heroku createを実行するとアプリケーションのURLとリモートが作成されます。

```
$ heroku create
```

リモート内容は .git/configで確認することができます。

```
$ cat .git/config
```

内容は初期状態だと以下のようになっていました。

```
[remote "heroku"]
    url = https://git.heroku.com/rails appname.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

urlがrailsのアプリケーション名になっているのでherokuのアプリケーション名に変えます。herokuのアプリ名を調べるには `heroku apps` を実行すればよいようです。

```
$ heroku apps
```

.git/configを書き換えます。

```
$ vi .git/config
```

```
[remote "heroku"]
    url = https://git.heroku.com/heroku_appname.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

これでとりあえず403エラーは出なくなりました。

```
$ git push heroku master
```